# Using elements within a class

Tags: html, css

Ok so I have been learning web programming for about 2 months, and have been taking online courses but for the last couple weeks I honestly still could not wrap my head around the concept of this

Take my navigation page of my website for example where I have

```
  <ul class = "main-nav js--main-nav">

    <li><a href = "#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Sign up</a></li>

  </ul>
```

Now in my CSS I have

```
.main-nav
{
    list-style:none;
    float:right;
}

.main-nav li
{
    display:inline-block;   
}

.main-nav li a
{

    text-decoration:none;

}
```

You see, I am very confused as to put my styling within `.main-nav li`, or `.main-nav li a`. For example if I put `text-decoration: none` within my `.main-nav li`, it won't work. Similarly if I do `display: inline-block`, it doesn't work either.

I just really don't understand why anything goes where it is, what exactly is the structure of all this? Why can I not text decorate within the `li` element? The link and the `li` element are attached so this seems weird. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: As far as the `text-decoration` goes, you have the LI with no underline, containing the A which by default has an underline. Since it's the A's underline you want to get rid of, that's where the style needs to go.

Comment: You can apply a text decoration to `li`, it just won't have an effect a descendant `a` because there is already a default rule for `a` setting its `text-decoration` to `underline`, so you need to overwrite the `a` rule.

Comment: that makes sense...  How about the inline-block then?

Comment: Your are not clear about that. Where did you try to apply `display: inline-block` to and what did you expect that should happen.

Comment: I want the "About us" and "Sign up" to appear side by side, so I used inline-block. If I put this inline-block in main-nav li a{ } , my desired effect does not occur, however as it is now, it works. Just wondering why.

Comment: I can understand that you might expect that `text-decoration`  for `li` might affect it the `a` which is a descendant, but I can't understand is why you expect that a change to the `display` of `a` should affect its ascendent (the `li` will still have `list-item` as its `display`).

Answer (score 1):

```css
/*Now in my CSS I have*/
.main-nav
{
    list-style:none;
    /* float:right; */
}

.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav li a
{

    text-decoration:inherit;

}
```

```html
  <ul class = "main-nav js--main-nav">

    <li><a href = "#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Sign up</a></li>

  </ul>
```

In the above example you will see that you can indeed declare the text-decoration property in the LI tag.  You just have to also declare it in the A tag and inherit.  What this does is inherits what the parent or container has.  See the following links: 
[text decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)
and
[Iheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance)

Mozilla Developer Network is a wonderful resource.  Just keep on learning and eventually these things will become second nature...it just takes time.

I commented out the float: right because it was not needed in my example.

Comment: two things, if i used inherit, in the main-nav li, will it inherit from "main-nav". Also why does display: inline-block, not work if I try to put it inside the main-nav li a{} section? My desired effect which currently works, is to have the two list elements side by side

Comment: 1.) I am not exactly clear on meaning of the first question.  The child element will inherit from the first parent it is declared in, as in the example.  Check out the link on inheritance in the answer and explore.
2.) If you apply inline-block to the A tags, its just not going to be shown side by side because the A tag is an only child. The inline-block needs to be applied to siblings which is why it works for the LI tags and thus they appear side by side.
I hope I have understood your comment and I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand. I guess this is something I just need to develop a sense for from experience